# Why X-RateLimit-Remaining -1 in response header while using spring cloud api gateway ratelimit with redis?

Tags: spring, gateway, rate-limiting

I implemented ratelimit with redis in my spring cloud api gateway. Here is part of `application.yml`:

```
spring:  
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: test-rest-service
          uri: lb://test-rest-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/test/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/test/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                key-resolver: "#{@userRemoteAddressResolver}"
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 2
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 3
```

I called a GET API via postman and checked response header.

```
X-RateLimit-Remaining -1
X-RateLimit-Burst-Capacity 3
X-RateLimit-Replenish-Rate 2
```

The rate limit is not working. Why am I getting negative value for `X-RateLimit-Remaining`? What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because there was no Redis instance launched. You have two options:

1) Download and run a Redis instance using docker:

```
docker run --name redis -d redis
```

2) You can use in testing an **Embedded Redis Server** as it is explained in the [following article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-embedded-redis) by adding the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And including the following snippet:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestRedisConfiguration {

    private RedisServer redisServer;

    public TestRedisConfiguration() {
        this.redisServer = new RedisServer(6379);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        redisServer.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        redisServer.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently. In my case, there was an older version of Redis installed which caused X-RateLimit-Remaining to be set to -1 constantly.

```
redis-cli shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**: SCG (Spring Cloud Gateway) is not able to connect with redis server

**Fix**: Connect SCG to redis server to get correct headers

## Details

#### Check debug logs to verify the issue

You may check logs by adding the following property in application.yml

```
logging:
    level:
        root: DEBUG
```

You will see the following logs when you will execute a request (and that request response will come with X-RateLimit-Remaining -1).

```
2023-04-02T15:56:19.293+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [or-http-epoll-3] io.lettuce.core.RedisClient              : Trying to get a Redis connection for: redis://localhost:50989?timeout=1s
2023-04-02T15:56:19.545+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [or-http-epoll-3] i.l.c.r.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider    : Allocating executor io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup
2023-04-02T15:56:19.545+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [or-http-epoll-3] i.l.c.r.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider    : Creating executor io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup
2023-04-02T15:56:19.547+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [or-http-epoll-3] i.l.c.r.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider    : Adding reference to io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup@5231db1e, existing ref count 0
2023-04-02T15:56:19.620+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [or-http-epoll-3] io.lettuce.core.RedisClient              : Resolved SocketAddress localhost/<unresolved>:50989 using redis://localhost:50989?timeout=1s
2023-04-02T15:56:19.620+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [or-http-epoll-3] io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient      : Connecting to Redis at localhost/<unresolved>:50989
2023-04-02T15:56:19.656+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [llEventLoop-5-1] i.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler   : [channel=0x1c09eca5, [id: 0x63790b3a] (inactive), epid=0x1, chid=0x1] channelRegistered()
2023-04-02T15:56:19.673+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [llEventLoop-5-1] io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient      : Connecting to Redis at localhost/<unresolved>:50989: localhost/<unresolved>:50989

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:50989
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:164) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:129) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:359) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:710) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:687) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:489) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-04-02T15:56:19.678+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [llEventLoop-5-1] io.lettuce.core.RedisChannelHandler      : closeAsync()
2023-04-02T15:56:19.678+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [llEventLoop-5-1] i.lettuce.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint  : [unknown, epid=0x1] closeAsync()
2023-04-02T15:56:19.680+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [llEventLoop-5-1] i.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler   : [channel=0x1c09eca5, [id: 0x63790b3a] (inactive), epid=0x1, chid=0x1] channelUnregistered()
2023-04-02T15:56:19.685+05:00 DEBUG 860131 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.c.g.f.ratelimit.RedisRateLimiter     : Error calling rate limiter lua

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1602) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1533) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1083) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:479) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:105) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.call(MonoSupplier.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen.subscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at io.github.resilience4j.reactor.circuitbreaker.operator.MonoCircuitBreaker.subscribe(MonoCircuitBreaker.java:38) ~[resilience4j-reactor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:77) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromFluxOperator.subscribe(MonoFromFluxOperator.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:350) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:391) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2072) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:415) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:431) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:663) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:274) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:50989
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.3.RELEASE.jar:6.2.3.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.3.RELEASE.jar:6.2.3.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:350) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.3.RELEASE.jar:6.2.3.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.3.RELEASE.jar:6.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:111) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:111) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1531) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:50989
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:164) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:129) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:359) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:710) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:687) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:489) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.90.Final.jar:4.1.90.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

#### Spin Up Redis Server

Spin up a Redis server by executing the following docker-compose script using `docker compose -f {file-name} up -d`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    polar-redis:
        image: "redis:latest"
        container_name: "polar-redis"
        ports:
          - "127.0.0.1:50988:6379"
```

#### Add redis props in spring application

Add the following props in application.yml to connect with redis server (I deliberately changed the default port of redis to 50988)

```
spring:
    data:
        redis:
            connect-timeout: 2s
            host: localhost
            port: 50988
            timeout: 1s
```

Now, restart your application. SCG should be able to connect with redis server.

Thanks